# Python rstrip is not striping out the character and everything that follows it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to just have the address without the apartment number so I used `rstrip` to get rid of the `#` and all the text after it. But it is not working.

Input:

```
'123 Sesame Street #6D'.rstrip('#6D')
```

Output:

```
'123 Sesame Street #6D'
```

Desired Output:

```
'123 Sesame Street'
```

How can I get it to work?

Comment: I cannot reproduce, it outputs `'123 Sesame Street '` for me, although note, the string you passed in will strip any of the characters that happen to be at the end in any order. So, `'123 Sesame Street #6D'.rstrip('D6#')` will give you the same thing

Comment: @JonClements: the command itself still works so the OP must clarify that (rather useless) observation "it is not working". Possibly their computer stopped working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rstrip()` function is intended to strip individual *characters* occurring at the right side of a string.  Use `re.sub` instead:

```
address = "123 Sesame Street #6D"
out = re.sub(r'\s*#[^#]+$', '', address)
print(out)
```

This prints:

```
123 Sesame Street
```

Comment: `'123 Sesame Street #6D'.rstrip('D6#')`  works already. The OP has a different problem

Comment: I suspect the OP probably wants: `address.rpartition('#')[0]` or similar here and that using a regex is possibly overkill...

Comment: @JonClements Driving a Ferrari to go pick up a carton of milk down the street is probably overkill, but that wouldn't stop me from driving a Ferrari. `:-)`

Comment: Except I'd probably send the butler off to fetch the milk and go drive the Ferrari somewhere worthwhile :)

Comment: I used `address.rpartition('#')[0]` courtesy of @JonClements